# Drupal 7 load profile2 programmatically

Tags: drupal-7, profile, hook-form-alter

I have two profile2 profiles defined - main and customer_profile. Also, I have a node type called Customer.

When creating a new Customer node, I would like to load the custom_profile form. The idea is to create a node and a profile simultaneously.

**I know it's definately a hook_form_alter solution but can someone tell me how to programmatically load a profile while creating or editing a Customer node.**

Answer (score 4):

You can load profile type and data by using these function

```
$types = profile2_get_types();
profile2_load_by_user($account, $type_name = NULL)
```

For Example :

```
$types = profile2_get_types();
    if (!empty($types)) {
        foreach ($types as $type) {
            $profile = profile2_load_by_user($uid, $type->type);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if you are able to load the customer_profile form, you will need to handle the values separately as they are two different nodes.

I would suggest capturing those fields in the customer node form, and then create a customer_profile programmatically from the values.

If you want to get the profile2 form itself then you can use something like

```
module_load_include('inc', 'profile2_page', 'profile2_page');
$profile2 = profile2_by_uid_load($uid, 'seeker_profile');
$entity_form = entity_ui_get_form('profile2', $profile2, 'edit');
```

and then add that to the form you want to place it in.

Answer (score 0):

You can load full profile data using profile2_load_by_user(); 
params like:-

```
profile2_load_by_user($account,$type_name)
$account: The user account to load profiles for, or its uid.
$type_name: To load a single profile, pass the type name of the profile to load
```

So code like bellow

```
$account->uid = $existingUser->uid;
$type_name = 'user_about';
$profile =  profile2_load_by_user($account, $type_name);
//$profile variable have full data of profile fields
//changing data profile2 fields 
if(isset($_POST['field_user_first_name'])&& !empty($_POST['field_user_first_name'])){
    $profile->field_user_first_name['und'][0]['value'] = $_POST['field_user_first_name'];
}
profile2_save($profile);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well When creating a new Profile , Profile2 fields are not visible until a manual save is done.
To Automatically create the profile2 object , We use rules Module 
Step
1) Go to Drupal admin/config/workflow/rules
2) create new rule
3) Give a name and Select in react/event "After saving a new user account"
4)  Action,>> Add Action >> Execute custom PHP code 
5) insert php code

    `$profile = profile_create(array('type' => 'profile2 type machine name', 'uid' => $account->uid));
    profile2_save($profile);`


6)Save >> Save changes.

This will create profile2 field when a new user is Created.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar need for creating a custom tab at the user page and loading the user profile2 form in it.

Here is a snap code of how I managed to accomplish just that:

MYMODULE.module https://gist.github.com/4223234

MYMODULE_profile2_MYPROFILE2TYPE.inc https://gist.github.com/4223201

Hope it helps.